# Passing around structs

Tags: go, struct

I am new to go and coming from a Ruby background. I am trying to understand code structuring in a world without classes and am probably making the mistake wanting to do it "the Ruby way" in Go.

I am trying to refactor my code to make it more modular / readable so I moved the loading of the configuration file to its own package. Good idea?

```
package configuration

import "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"

type Config struct {
    Temperatures []struct {
        Degrees int
        Units string
    }
}

func Load() Config {
    var cnf Config
    _, err := toml.DecodeFile("config", &cnf)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return cnf
}
```

Now, in my main package:

```
package main

import "./configuration"

var conf Configuration = configuration.Load()
```

Gives `undefined: Config`. I understand why. I could copy the struct definition in the main package but that's not very DRY.

It's my understanding passing around structs like this is a bad practice as it makes your code harder to understand (now everyone needs to know about my Config struct).

Is hiding logic in a package like I am trying to do here a good idea in Go? If so, what's the "Go" way to pass this Config struct around?

Comment: First, you don't need to copy a struct between packages if it's exported. I think you mean to use `configuration.Config`? Also, don't use relative imports for anything but a quick test. *Always* use the full import path.

Comment: See "How to Write Go Code" for a tutorial on [how to write a library and use it from the main program](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library).

Comment: @MuffinTop Thanks, that's a great resource!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your main package you should specify

```
var conf configuration.Config = configuration.Load()
```

`configuration` refers to your imported package and `Config` is the exported struct (uppercase name) from that package. But you can also omit this, as the type can be inferred

```
var conf = configuration.Load()
```

As a side note: please don't use relative imports

Answer (score 1):

in Go imports you always declare the full path of you package, dont use relative paths in imports, best example is that toml import `import "github.com/BurntSushi/toml"` that exist in: 
GOPATH/src/github.com/BurntSushi/toml 
GOPATH/pkg/_/github.com/BurntSushi/toml

Then build you package and `main.go`

```
package main

import "mypackage/configuration"

func main() {
   // configuration contain all funcs & structs 
   var conf configuration.Config = configuration.Load()
}
```

Go it is not ruby.

Ref Packages: https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just import the configuration package and then do Go's variable declaration/instatiation shortcut? Maybe I'm missing something.

```
package main

import "mypackage/configuration"

func main() {
   conf := configuration.Load()
}
```

Comment: The shortcut doesn't work for me as I would like to use my `conf` var in all the different functions so I declare it outside of the main function. But I see what you are explaining. Thanks.